# Problem dockerizing a R Shiny application with the package ggvis

Tags: r, docker, shiny, ggvis

I have some trouble dockerizing a Shiny app. The problem comes from the dockerization of the package ggvis. Here is a minimal example.

The shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

df<-iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("size"),
  br(),
  ggvisOutput("cloudPoint"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$size <- renderText({
    nrow(df)
  })
  
  output$cloudPoint <- reactive({
      df %>%
      ggvis::ggvis(~Sepal.Length,~Sepal.Width)%>%
      bind_shiny("cloudPoint")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run it, I get the following app with the ggvis visualisation and a textOutput of the number of rows of the dataframe (150):

[image]

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('ggvis'))"

COPY /shinyapp/ /srv/shiny-server/
```

Now, when I dockerize it and open the container in my browser I get the following application without the textOutput 150:

[image]

Do you have any idea about the problem ?
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Is there any error or messages from Shiny in the docker container? If you use the developer tools in your browser to see the source, can you see the div for the `size` text output in the HTML? When you aren't using the docker container, does it show up properly in your browser (i.e., not the RStudio viewer)?

Comment: Hi @Marcus , there is no error in the docker container and it does show up properly in my brower outside of the docker container.

Comment: In the developer tools I have this line:
```<div id="size" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite"></div```
together with
```div#size.shiny-text-output.shiny-bound-output | 1506 x 0```
pointing on the top of the page/my tabs..

Comment: It seems that it's creating the placeholder but it's not updating. Are there any javascript errors in the console? If you remove the plot, does it display the 150?

Comment: There is no javascript error in the console and I soon as I comment the line ```ggvisOutput("cloudPoint"),``` the 150 appears.

Comment: Are you able to force the `size` output to invalidate/recalculate? For example, add an action button `actionButton("click", "click"),` to the UI and then change the server to `output$size <- renderText({ nrow(df) + input$click})`

Comment: Interesting.. 
The 150 doesn't appear at first. After clicking on the action button, it appears normally (and increasing as I click)..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by changing the parent image in the first line of the Dockerfile `FROM rocker/shiny-verse` by `FROM rocker/shiny:4.0.5`.

Remark that with the parent image `FROM rocker/shiny:latest` it doesn't work.